# Android ViewPager from custom library Bug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager

I learning, how to create a android library and I create a simple onboarding Library. But I have a problem with my ViewPager from my custom module.

When I swipe in right and left, my seconds item is not display or first and second view is overlay.

I don't understand where the problem comes from

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![ ][3]][3]

Main class in my library:

```
public class OnBoardingView extends FrameLayout implements LifecycleObserver {

    public OnBoardingView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        this.initialize(context, null);
    }

    public OnBoardingView(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initialize(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.onboarding_view_root, this);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Hello world 1");
        list.add("Hello world 2");
        list.add("Hello world 3");

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id._screenPager);
        OnBoardingAdapter<String> onBoardingAdapter = new OnBoardingAdapter<String>(context, list);
        viewPager.setAdapter(onBoardingAdapter);
    }
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class OnBoardingAdapter<T> extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<T> onBoardingList;

    public OnBoardingAdapter(Context context, List<T> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.onBoardingList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.onBoardingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.getClass() == object.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.onboarding_screen_view, null);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
}
```

My XML file to content ViewPager :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/_screenPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

My Xml for each page:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="onboarding_screen_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in main main_activity file I call this to display my module:

```
    <com.domaine.onboarding.OnBoardingView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: To start off, try posting your codes as snippets not images so that they can be read easily.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I updated my question in adding the codes as snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return view instead of container

If you want to achieve this easily try to use `viewpager2`, you can use adapter that similar with `recyclerview` adapter

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Comment: Thanks for your comment I fixed to in removing getClass() from isViewFromObject()